# Corrupted Storage Spaces Virtual Disk

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I'm dealing with an odd issue I have with Storage Spaces. I have been using it for a while now on two machines without major issue, until today. The machine in question has:

Storage Pool (all OK):

[image: View of storage pools on the machine]

Virtual Disk (**notice the Unhealthy status**):

[image: View of virtual disks in the pool]

And the drives themselves:

[image: View of physical drives]

*FASTPARITY1* is a disk with **Bitlocker enabled** and automount off. Whenever the PC is started and user wants to access data, they are prompted for Bitlocker password.

*FASTPARITY2* is a disk without any encryption. It is formatted with NTFS and is available after logging into Windows.

What have I done that has caused this:

Due to some hardware upgrading today, I have done the following: I have unplugged all physical discs from PC1 (where everything worked and PC1 was properly shut down like always) and connected them to PC2. I knew from before that this works and Storage Spaces on PC2 should pick everything up automatically. I have noticed that virtual disk FASTPARITY2 was immediately recognized by PC2's Storage Spaces, while the FASTPARITY1 was not. I went into Storage Spaces UI and this popped up:

[image: View of Storage Spaces UI]

When I scroll down to physical drives section, there is no issue:

[image: View of physical drives in Storage Spaces UI]

When I try to manually connect the detached virtual disk, I am greeted with strange error:

[image: Error while trying to connect the detached virtual disk]

I thought to myself: "OK, there's something wrong here, let's plug them back to PC1 where it all worked 5 minutes ago." But situation at PC1 is identical, same errors, same issues. The Storage Space seems fine (reports healthy), but the bitlocker-encrypted virtual disk reports unhealthy status and cannot be accessed.

The data is mostly backed up elsewhere, but some would still be lost if I can't recover from this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to execute `Repair-VirtualDisk` from PowerShell, but it immediately ends with no output. Here's the command: `Repair-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName FASTPARITY1`.

Comment: Furthermore, I was able to find that running `Get-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName FASTPARITY1 | Format-List -Property *` yields more information. There, I can see that `DetachedReason` property has a value of `Majority Disks Unhealthy`. According to some [Microsoft](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/blob/master/WindowsServerDocs/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-states.md) sources, this is considered catastrophic failure. However, ReclaiMe seems to be able to access the volume just fine, so I'm in touch with them to see if they can workout the Bitlocker part.

Comment: Did you solved it? (I have the same Problem)