# Is it safe to use Windows 11 Mirror Storage Spaces with BitLocker Auto-Unlock

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, bitlocker, software-raid, storage-spaces

There [have been reports](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b3fbf6b-a814-4d02-ae7b-b71a40126f8e/windows-10-bitlocker-storage-spaces-autounlock-volumes-getting-lost-every-time?forum=win10itprosecurity) [from a few years](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/issue-with-some-parity-storage-spaces-after-updating-to-windows-10-version-2004-and-windows-server-version-2004-dff27583-e9ee-2cd5-1107-f455771c30fe) [back](https://superuser.com/questions/1542358/corrupted-storage-spaces-virtual-disk) (albeit both about Windows 10, not 11) regarding some issues / incompatibilities that lead to data loss / corruption of using Windows Storage Spaces where 2 or more drives are set up in mirror configuration, together with BitLocker protecting that Storage Space Volume, set to auto-unlock when PC boots.

Storage Spaces are needed for data redundancy (2-way mirror). While BitLocker is used for privacy.

So, just wanted to confirm, if such a combination is indeed safe, and there would be no issues.

And will using VeraCrypt instead of BitLocker make things any different?

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the link you provided, the issue was affecting parity configurations and was resolved 3 years ago.

From my experience, I can only write that I'm using Storage Spaces in the mirror mode on Windows 11, with Bitlocker and auto unlocking. I use it for about six months and I have no problems. However, I have two offline backups of my data, just for sure.

I can't guarantee, and probably no one will, there will be no issues for you.